# SearchBoost UrlFriendly Unwelcome Display

Tags: dotnetnuke

With our dotnetnuke site we have installed SearchBoost.

For the most part the searched results display fine except for many search queries that display the url of the result.

Bad URL displayed
https://{Site URL}/tabid/23/Default.aspx

Good URL displayed wanted
https://{Site URL}/friendly/name/of/page/currently/browsed

We have posted to the module author and haven't heard anything so figured I try posting here for more visibility https://community.plantanapp.com/Forum/Question-Details/qid/2185

Current Version of DOTNETNUKE 9.3.2
Search Boost Module Version 5.1.57

Within the SearchBoost Search Settings we have tried:
Excluding item from Search results from Portals > Page (unchecking)
Excluding item from Search results Exceptions > Tab (adding 23 and urls)
Re-indexed
Cleared Cache

Even trying to remove the item from the index is problematic

Comment: Can't help, but for more visibility you could also post to the forums of the [DNN Community web site](https://dnncommunity.org).